# Promotion Publishing issue

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I have added 4 components under "What" Tab for  a Promotion in SmartTarget Tab in ContentManagerExplorer Trdion. And then saved the promotion and Published those 4 components.

Now component1 and Component2 are having same Template whereas Component3 and Component4 are having same template.

When i publish this promotion, i can see that only Component1 and Component2 are getting deployed in Fredhopper whereas Component3 and Component4 are not getting deployed in Fredhopper "fredhopper\indexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01" location.

Can you please throw light on this, why it is not getting published.

Please note i am using  fredhopper-7.5.2.10 and SDL8.5

Comment: There is a Template Building Block ("Add to Experience Optimization", I believe, it used to be called "Add to SmartTarget") that needs to be added to the component template. My guess is that Template 1 has it, and Template 2 doesn't have it.

Comment: Yes it is missing in one Template and i have added it now and republished Component again still not working.

Answer (score 4):

You should check couple of things:

**1) is component getting to Fredhopper?** You can verify this by checking `fredhopper\indexer\data\xml\processed\`, `fredhopper\indexer\data\xml\incoming\`, `fredhopper\indexer\data\xml\suspended\`, or `fredhopper\indexer\data\xml\rejected\` folders. If these folders do contain xml related to your components it means that they are in fredhopper. They were either processed or rejected/suspended. After that you can check logs for errors. If component is in none of these folders, its most probably not comming to fredhopper (as @Nuno explained template doesn't have "Add to Experience Optimization" block).

**2) Is component listed in preview:** `indexer:10180/preview/`? You can check your items in fredhopper with `/preview/` and check what exactly fredy is containing.

3) Debug this additionally if needed. For us sometimes fredy rejects items when they are not in sync with schema, but all of this is in fredhopper logs. Have fun reading it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have selected "Publish as Dynamic component" in the component template and republish it again